# Save Firebase Storage Video and Play with AVPlayerViewController

Tags: swift, firebase, avplayer, firebase-storage

Building an app that allows users to upload media to Firebase Storage. Upload seems to be working fine, however I can't get video downloads to play.

I saved a file to the app to test the AVPlayer and it works perfect.

```
func handleGesture() {
    print("handle gesture")
    if detailMediaType == "Video"{
        performSegueWithIdentifier("toVideoView", sender: self)
        print("video segue called")
    }
} 

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if(segue.identifier == "toVideoView"){

        let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Apartment Ceiling Collapse- Queens, NY", ofType: "mp4")
        var movieUrl = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path!)
        let filename = getDocumentsDirectory().stringByAppendingPathComponent("movie")
        let videoData = NSData(contentsOfURL: movieUrl)
        videoData!.writeToFile(filename, atomically: true)

        self.avPlayer = AVPlayer(URL: movieUrl)
        self.avPlayerViewController.player = self.avPlayer

        self.presentViewController(self.avPlayerViewController, animated: false) { () -> Void in self.avPlayerViewController.player?.play()

        }
    }
}
```

Edit: I am now trying to download using downloadURLWithCompletion

```
FIRStorage.storage().referenceForURL(detailFullsizeUrl).downloadURLWithCompletion { (URL, error) -> Void in
            if (error != nil)
            {
                print(error!)
            }
            else
            {

                self.firebaseUrl = URL!

                print("firebaseUrl")
                print(self.firebaseUrl)
                self.avPlayer = AVPlayer(URL: self.firebaseUrl)
                self.avPlayerViewController.player = self.avPlayer 
            }
        }
```

I get an AVPlayerViewController with a black screen. When I access the "firebaseUrl" from the web, it downloads a text file that looks like gibberish.

**Solution:** 
Changed up my approach. No longer saving to device. Instead I grabbed the "downloadUrl" metadata from the Firebase Storage object and pass it directly to the AVPlayerViewController.

```
let avPlayerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
var avPlayer:AVPlayer? = nil

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
      FIRStorage.storage().referenceForURL(detailFullsizeUrl).metadataWithCompletion { (metadata, error) in
        if error != nil{
            print("error getting metadata")
        } else {
            let downloadUrl = metadata?.downloadURL()
            print(downloadUrl)

            if downloadUrl != nil{
                self.avPlayer = AVPlayer(URL: downloadUrl!)
                self.avPlayerViewController.player = self.avPlayer
                print("downloadUrl obtained and set")
            }
        }
    }   
}

func handleGesture() {
    print("handle gesture")
    self.presentViewController(self.avPlayerViewController, animated: true) { () -> Void in
        self.avPlayerViewController.player?.play()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check question. I updated it with the correct solution found on YouTube here: [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zG7qgyA5Gb4)